# Top Questions of the Week #8

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into <del>week 8</del> post 8 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each we week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, none of the current writers had enough experience or knowledge to write an article about DEC-tapes (not even Matt Jenkins!).

So instead we made him write a blog post about his question about [compression and encryption as be found here.](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/03/21/compression-and-encryption/)

Answer (score 12):

[How can I read a reel-to-reel tape from the 1970s?](https://superuser.com/questions/252393/how-can-i-read-a-reel-to-reel-tape-from-the-1970s)

I have been following this question since its inception and have found it quite interesting. Also, as far as I can tell, this is the only question about DECtapes on Super User and might be the only question about them we ever see (who knows, maybe they will make a comeback!:P). So I think this question and DEC-tapes deserve some time in the spotlight.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, as I've been following as well.